# ESTA, first name confusion

Tags: usa, passports, tickets, esta

I have gotten my ESTA approved, and understood that I were only to give 
the FIRST of our names listed under "Given names" in the passports.

On the ticket and the passport information however, I have included all 
the names listed under "Given names". For example: "Carl Johan". Our airline company says that it is OK on their part, they just check that the ESTA is approved (which it is). But I am wondering if we can experience any problems when arriving in the US?

*To clarify* 
Info provided in my ESTA 
First name: Carl

Info provided on my ticket/passport info to airline: 
First name: Carl Johan

Do I need to apply for a new ESTA and include "Johan" in the first name 
field? It feels a bit awkward that the ESTA and ticket info should differ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have done exactly this two years ago and had no problems whatsoever about it. This does not mean you won't have problems but I highly doubt it would be an issue. That is confirming what your airline says.

I.e. I have two first names but routinely only use the first of those. My ESTA only has the first first name while the flight ticket was issued with my full name (i.e. two first names) as it is also in my passport. Neither airline nor immigration nor anyone else even bothered about it.

Given the wording of the ESTA application rules that you cite, I even assume this is the intended behavior.
As @phoog pointed out in a comment below, in the US second and subsequent given names are generally called middle names, so leaving them out of an entry called "first name" would be quite normal.

Comment: Anyway in the US second and subsequent given names are generally called middle names, so leaving them out of an entry called "first name" would be quite normal.

Comment: I am going to go for that this world isn't as bureaucratic as I am fearing, and go with only the first name :) Thanks.

Comment: @phoog do you mind if I incorporate that very helpful comment of yours in my answer or would you like to post your own answer with that?

Comment: @mts please do. It would be better to have all the information in one place.